# Динамическое изменение языка Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, локализация

почитал разные статьи, но так и не нашел **как реализовать динамическое изменение языка.**

Пример: Я меняю на своем телефоне язык(захожу в настройки телефона->язык->английский язык\русский язык) потом открываю свое приложение и в приложение в зависимости от выбранного языка на телефоне(русский\английский) переводит приложение на выбранной в системе язык

Есть ли какая-то документация или информация как это можно реализовать на Kotlin/Java?

Comment: плохо читал. Это написано везде. Неужели в "разных статьях" ничего не было про ресурс strings.xml?

Comment: Здесь я когда-то отвечал на этот вопрос, воспользуйтесь поиском

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через Андроид Студио в директории `res` создать новый ресурсный файл `Android resource file`, который назвать `strings`, при этом выбрать в дереве слева локаль и указать какую. В результате появятся 2 файла strings, один дефолтный, второй - для выбранной локали. Тогда при переключении языка системы приложение  будет менять источник строковых значений. https://ibb.co/XYvsD0X

Answer (score 1):

Правой кнопкой мыши на Values -> New -> Value Resourse Filу, далее как на картинке. Выберите нужный вам язык.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее в тексте программы обращение такое:

```
ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.diag6)
```

где diag6 в файлах strings.xml(RU)

```
<string name="diag6">Частота вращения коленвала</string>
```

strings.xml(en)

```
<string name="diag6">Crankshaft speed</string>
```