# Как сохранить и вытаскивать ресурсные файлы(string.xml) из базы данных android studio?

Tags: android, sql, строки, kotlin

имеется приложение в котором присутствуют два ресурсных файла string-English.xml и string-Rush.xml в них хранятся строки на русском и английских языках приложения. Мне нужно менять язык приложения в зависимости от изменения языка системно на телефоне

**Проблема заключается в том, что я создал два столбца text_en и text_ru где должны сохранятся и позже вытаскиваться ресурсные файлы на русском и английском, но не понял как сохранять ресурсные файлы в базу данных, а позже их вытаскивать.
Как это возможно реализовать?**

Comment: По-подробнее, пожалуйста. Непонятно зачем перекладывать ресурсы в базу, ещё и целыми файлами и как вы потом хотите их использовать.

Comment: @woesss у меня приложение на русском и английском языке, в ресурсных файлах у меня хранятся строки, которые хранят  в себе строки языка. В бд у меня хранится текст строки чтобы при переключении приложения на другой язык он их отображал

Comment: Что-то вы наворотили лишнего. Два файла, strings.xml и string.xml(RU). В одном русский текст, в другом английский. Обращаетесь в коде к имени строки, и в зависимости от системной настройки вам выдается русский или английский текст

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1410833/%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0-android/1411174#1411174

Comment: @ArtyMorris А что делать в случае если у меня строк 100..?Обращаться индивидуально к каждой через getResources().getString(R.string.name)?

Comment: Да, к каждой textview вы прописываете или програмно или в xml ссылку на строку в файле. И всё. В разметке пишется    android:text="@string/setting149". К примеру

Comment: @KotKotikov, а вы как хотите к ним обращаться? Получить массивом все сразу? Для этого можно оформить в `<string-array>`. Если нужно делать выборку строк по каким-то сложным условиям и их (строк) будут сотни - то лучше конечно использовать базу, заполнить заранее и положить в ассеты, либо в любой удобный вам формат и заполнить во время выполнения.

Comment: @woesss по-хорошему  локально их вытаскивать через getResources, а потом в базу данных cохранять